# Share data between ios applications

Tags: ios, swift, share

I have to share the login data between two applications, so that in app `br.com.companyB.app2` can use the login data of application `br.com.companyA.app1` as in this:

[image: image.]

I've done a lot of research, and they all lead me to using "apps group". But I've seen that to use this, apps must be on the same developer account, but in my case I have two apps on separate accounts. I also saw that using the API would help me, but I'm looking for a "native" way. Is there any way to share data between these applications?

Comment: The native way would be an app group to store shared information like session/user data.

Comment: But I can not use group apps because they are not in the same developer account.

Comment: As you said yourself, thats how its done natively. If you can't use that then you can't do it natively.. you'll need a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, app groups are indeed **restricted to a single developer team only**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW21

As far as I know, there is no native workaround as apps are sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

If the apps are not on  the same developer portal then the answer is no , you can share the data by webServices not locally ,other option is using `UIPasteboard` with suite but it's neither the right nor the secure way to go